Where is the degeneracy of the bands in this band structure and what does it mean?
this is my first question here, so please forgive me if some details are missing. I will try to provide as much as i can.
So for the question: I had a lecture on the nearly free electron approximation in my solid state introductory course. There we discussed the band structure and were presented with the picture below in the extended-zone scheme. It was said, that there was a degeneracy in the bands but also splitting of this degeneracy with a lattice potential, that is strongest at the border of the brillouin-zone. Now i am wondering what degeneracy means in terms of bands and the picture and also if i can see the splitting of degeneracy in the picture at all. (Also i don't really understand, where the positions of the bands come from...shouldn't they be on top of each other?)
My own researched has me thinking, that the points where the two bands touch at the boundary of the Brillouin zone are degenerate. But i still dont know why, because i thought degenerate meant, that two k-vektors correspond to the same energy and that would be true for every point on the nu=0 band. Also i dont get, what the other points mean, that are marked with an x. Is this a trick to see the degeneracy splitting?
Sorry for my vague understanding and every slight improvement would be appreciated,thanks.


In the absence of a lattice potential, the energy eigenstates are simply the momentum eigenstates. The lattice potential can couple together momentum states differing by a momentum $\Delta p = h / L$ where $h$ is Planck's constant and $L$ is the periodicity of the lattice.
The momentum eigenstates "at the edges of the first Brouillin zone", i.e. those with momentum $\pm \Delta p/2$, are degenerate in the absence of a lattice potential but can be coupled to one another by the lattice potential. In the limit of weak coupling one can determine how the lattice potential "splits" this degenerate energy level by diagonalizing the associated 2x2 perturbation matrix. The lattice potential similarly couples together momentum eigenstates $-\Delta p / 2 + \delta p$ and $\Delta p / 2 + \delta p$, though these states are not perfectly degenerate so in general they are less strongly "mixed" by the lattice potential as $|\delta p|$ increases, i.e. the perturbation due to the lattice potential is weaker. The states marked by the "x"s and joined by the vertical dashed lines correspond to a small but finite $\delta p$.
The idea behind the extended zones is that, with the introduction of the lattice potential, $p$ is no longer a conserved quantity but the "crystal momentum", i.e. the momentum modulo $\Delta p$, is.


It was said, that there was a degeneracy in the bands but also splitting of this degeneracy with a lattice potential, that is strongest at the border of the brillouin-zone. Now i am wondering what degeneracy means in terms of bands and the picture and also if i can see the splitting of degeneracy in the picture at all. (Also i don't really understand, where the positions of the bands come from...shouldn't they be on top of each other?)

In my opinion, from the figure, you can tell that there is a degeneracy "at the border of the BZ" if you consider the labels $G_1$. In your figure, you are extending the BZ past $\pi/a$ to illustrate where the degeneracy comes from, which is that there is a periodicity of the potential and slightly to the left of the first BZ, you will see that the energy "splits" to two points (at $G_1$). Since you want a more compact form of the crystal lattice representation, you "fold" (this is the term used in some literature) the 2nd BZ (from $\pi/a$ to $2\pi/a$ and you see that at the border of the BZ, there are 2 energy levels for each k-position at $G_1$. And they are on top of each other, but you have to think of the Brillouin Zones in terms of the periodicity of the potential, not on the actual potential (which, as mentioned before, can be "folded" to represent the energy levels in a more compact form).

But i still dont know why, because i thought degenerate meant, that two k-vektors correspond to the same energy and that would be true for every point on the $\nu=0$ band.

Not for two k-vectors but that at a k-vector (represented vertically if you want to think about it) you have two possible energy values due to the crystal periodicity. The potential is not necessarily periodical with the crystal, rather what you do with the $\nu=0,1$ is to extend the BZ and see the folding process in a more intuititive way. With more complex crystals you may be able to see the degeneracy slightly clearer, but it is fundamental to see this first example to understand how the potential folding occurs (and in real crystals, the influence of defects in the band gaps).
